# Wrapper function around sum ignored by R data.table

Tags: r, sum, data.table, wrapper

I wrote a wrapper function to set default behavior, but it only works if I rename it:

```
mysum <- sum <- function(...){
    if('na.rm' %in% names(list(...))){
        return(base::sum(...))
    } else{
        return(base::sum(..., na.rm = TRUE))
    }
}
```

```
trnData[
    , 
    .(CZK=sum(czkAmount)), 
    by = day %>% weekdays()
]
```

still yields NAs.

```
trnData[
    , 
    .(CZK=mysum(czkAmount)), 
    by = day %>% weekdays()
]
```

Works.

What is going on?

Comment: There is already a `base R` `sum` function.  Perhaps it is using that `sum` function

Comment: see ?GForce. data.table overwrites sum for efficiency when it can. you should rename your function, or turn off the optimization.